# Reading keyboard input using cstdio

Tags: c, string, integer, stdio

What's wrong with the following C code? (updated)

```
int nfds = 0;
char c[2] = " ";
char ans[2] = " ";

printf("Test p or s [p,s]: p? ");
ans[0] = (char)getchar();
if (ans[0] != '\n')
  {
    ans[1] = '\0';
    printf("ans = %s\n", ans);
  }
else
  ans[0] = '\0';

/* FIXME: answering 's' -> nfds is never read */
printf ("Choose [0, 1, 2, 3]: 0? ");
c[0] = (char)getchar();
if (c[0] != '\n') 
  {
    c[1] = '\0';
    nfds = strtol(c, NULL, 10);
  }
else
  c[0] = '\0'
printf( "nfds=%d\n", nfds);
```

Answering "return" works, but answering "s+return" does not stop at print("Choose...") and continues as if "return" was already given?

Maybe better solution would be: First read a char/string in `ans`, default: `"return"` in char/string='s'/"s" ask next question to read in the integer `nfds`, default: `"return"`

Comment: Answering s^D works but not s^J(\n=return)

Answer (score 4):

First:

`c[2] = '\n';`

There is no `c[2]` in your array of two elements. Same for `ans`.

Second:

```
c[1] = getchar();
...
nfds = atoi(c);
```

Your array has two elements and a string has to be null terminated. By overwriting `c[1]` then `c` array cannot hold a string.

Be aware also that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int` and not a `char`, this is important if you have to compare its return value with `EOF`.

Also [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) function cannot do error checking, you should use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: `char ans[2] = " ";` means `c[1]` value is the null character. If you overwrite `c[1]`, `ans` is no longer a string.

Answer (score 1):

To build on what ouah said [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) returns an int value which would be the [decimal](http://asciitable.com) value of whatever key was pressed. So you should capture the users key stroke as a int then [typecast](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson11.html) it as a char and insert it into your char array.

```
int key_stroke;
char array[size]

key_stroke = getchar();
array[1] = (char)key_stroke;
```

Correct me if I am wrong but you are trying to process key strokes until the enter key is pressed? Which could be done much more simply and cleanly with the following code.

```
int key_stroke;
char array[size]

for(i = 0; ((char)key_stroke != '\n') && (i < size); i++)
{
  key_stroke = getchar();
  array[i] = (char)key_stroke;
}
```

The keys the user presses will be added to array[] until the enter key is pressed or until the array runs out of space. 'i' Will increase with every rotation so your index will automatically update.

Comment: How to add a comment, "return" closes the comment??